Xamarin to MAUI migration - ContentPresenter not displaying elements
I am working on a product migration from xamarine to MAUI. App has a login screen base view and a child view. base view is using contentpresenter to render child view. But content presenter is not displaying its elements. I tried all possible ways of debugging and figured out that element is being created, also is visible in visual tree and traceable in UI but its not directly being visible anyway. I read MAUI also supports content presenter same way as xamarine. Please review the code below and suggest solution. I tried multiple solutions though. For now testing purpose, i only have kept a label in content.
Base View: LoginBaseView
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:GMS.Classes.Forms;assembly=GMS.core"
             xmlns:svg="clr-namespace:GMS.svg;assembly=GMS.core"
             xmlns:assistant="clr-namespace:GMS.Components.Assistant"
             xmlns:banner="clr-namespace:GMS.Controls.Banner;assembly=GMS.core"
             x:Class="GMS.Components.AuthenticationManager.UI.BaseAndContainer.LoginBaseView"
             AutomationId="LoginView">
    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="20, 30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                <Label Text="This is a test label for visibility."
FontSize="24"
HorizontalOptions="Center"
VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
IsVisible="True"
                TextColor="Red"/>
                <ScrollView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" 
                            Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">



                    <ContentPresenter BackgroundColor="LightGray"/>



                </ScrollView>

                <banner:Banner Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                               BindingContext="{Binding Banner, Source={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                               IsVisible="{Binding Converter={StaticResource NullVisibilityConverter}}"
                               Margin="-20, 16, -20, 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>

LoginBaseView.Xaml.cs
public partial class LoginBaseView
{
    public LoginBaseView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}    

Child view: ProviderSelectionUi
<baseAndContainer:LoginBaseView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
                                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                                 xmlns:baseAndContainer="clr-namespace:GMS.Components.AuthenticationManager.UI.BaseAndContainer;assembly=GMS.core"
                                 x:Class="GMS.Components.AuthenticationManager.UI.ProviderSelection.ProviderSelectionUi"
                                 AutomationId="LoginView"
                                 Loaded="OnLoaded">
    <baseAndContainer:LoginBaseView.Content>
        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label x:Name="TestLabel"
                   Text="Welcome to the Login Page"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   FontSize="24"
                   TextColor="Black"/>

            <Label x:Name="TestLabel1"
       Text="Welcome to the Login Page"
       HorizontalOptions="Center"
       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       FontSize="24"
       TextColor="Orange"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </baseAndContainer:LoginBaseView.Content>
</baseAndContainer:LoginBaseView>

Content cs: ProviderSelectionUi.xaml.cs
public partial class ProviderSelectionUi
{
    public ProviderSelectionUi()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void OnLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Check if the label is found and rendered
        if (TestLabel != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"TestLabel is present. Text: {TestLabel.Text}, IsVisible: {TestLabel.IsVisible}");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("TestLabel not found.");
        }
    }

}

It is displaying the contentpresenter, but not the elements inside it. whereas inside elements can be tracked in visual tree

Did the contentpresenter not displaying elements on all the platforms?

I am trying it for windows platform for now

Use ContentPage instead of ContentView?
